# How to check if the field is empty using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i want to check if a field is empty using javascript.

below is the variable "result" if result.title field is not available or if its empty then i have to show a default title.

below is what are the conditions

```
- if the result.title is present show that as title
-if result.title is empty and name present show string "${name} matches"
- if result.title is empty and name is not present show string "default title"
```

below is what i have tried.

```
const defaultTitle = result?.title ?? "default title";
```

but this doesnt check for empty title field and other condition if name present or not.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

but this

Comment: What do you mean by field? And by empty (undefined, null, "")?

Comment: yes that i what i meant @Konrad

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether a string is empty (where empty is undefined, null or "") with something like:

```
!str || str === ''
```

such that `str` is a variable that might be undefined, null or a string.

In the example below I've reversed the logic so that it's checking whether the string is present or not as that is what your example appears to be referring to.

```js
const is_present = (str) => str && str !== '';

const get_title = (title, name) =>
  is_present(title) ? title :
  is_present(name)  ? name + ' matches' :
    'default title';

console.log("null, 'Foo':      " + get_title(null, 'Foo'));
console.log("'Bar', 'Foo':     " + get_title('Bar', 'Foo'));
console.log("'Bar', null:      " + get_title('Bar', null));
console.log("'', 'Foo':        " + get_title('', 'Foo'));
console.log("'', '':           " + get_title('', ''));
console.log("{}?.title, 'Foo': " + get_title({}?.title, 'Foo'));
```